# async await + toPromise hangs

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm using [ngx-stripe](https://github.com/richnologies/ngx-stripe) , and the createToken returns an Observable which I've tried to convert to a promise so that I can use Async/await. However, it looks as though the promise dosen't resolve. Debugging doesn't reveal anything, and my try/Catch blocks doesn't capture any errors.

I wanted to know whether I'm using the toPromise correctly :

```
import {
    Elements,
    Element as StripeElement,
    ElementsOptions,
    BankAccountData,
    StripeService
} from 'ngx-stripe';

constructor(
    public stripeService: StripeService,

) {}



async next() {
    let token: any;
    let account: BankAccountData = {
        country: this.country,
        currency: this.currency,
        account_holder_name: this.first_name + " " + this.last_name,
        account_holder_type: this.type,
        account_number: account_number,
        routing_number: routing_number
    };

    console.log("--> Creating Bankaccount Token", account);

    try {
        token = await this.stripeService.createToken("bank_account", account).toPromise();
    } catch (excep) {
        console.log(excep);
    }

    console.log("-->Token Generated : ", token);
}
```

#### EDIT

Debugger - if it helps. This is the last console output:

> Creating Bankaccount Token {country: "AU", currency: "aud", account_holder_name: "Someone Name", account_holder_type: "individual", account_number: "000123456", …}

[image]

*************************EDIT ***********************
I'm not sure why, but the code worked when I created a stackblitz.

I then compared the libraries in stackblitz and updated my angular, rxjs, rxjs-compat to match what was in stackblitz and tried again and I was getting the same result as before.

I then removed the toPromise() and changed it to :

```
this.stripeService.createToken("bank_account", account).subscribe(data => {
               console.log(data);
             });
```

I'm not sure what is limiting what my project has compared to what's in stackblitz. I'm not sure how to work out what the problem is, and the only thing I can think of is rebuilding the project from scratch.

Comment: `it looks as though the promise dosen't resolve` <= how do you know/test this theory?

Comment: For more help please include the code to `stripeService.createToken` in your question.

Comment: hi Igor, I'm just assuming as when debugging it reaches the code token = await.... and then just finishes. I checked the network and the URL was reached and responded successfully. Regarding the createToken it is from the library ngx-stripe which I've added as a link.

Comment: The start of my question seems to be chopped off, I'll edit it .

Comment: `I checked the network and the URL was reached and responded successfully.` <= that sounds like it is working, I am not sure what the problem is then? (maybe add `console.log("success ", token);` after `token = await ...`)

Comment: Sorry I had "console.log("-->Token Generated : ", token);" but must have removed it. I have other code such as checking for token null etc... which doesn't get executed.

Comment: I am confused, is `console.log("-->Token Generated : "` reached or do you mean it is hanging on the call to `createToken` (ie no response because network does not return). If you are getting a response what is the value of token?

Comment: The debugger doesn't reach the statement console.log("-->Token Generated : ", token); however, when I check the network I can see a call to the network with a successful response.

Comment: Can you attach the browsers debugger to see what happens? I would also change your error statement to this `console.error('Error occurred', excep);`. This is more visible in the log where as if `excep` was undefined I don't think anything would be in the log at all.

Comment: To more easily stop before the statement add this right before the stripeService call. `debugger;`. This will force the browser to break as long as you have the development console open.

Comment: Yup changed it to console.error and added the debugger and it hasn't altered the result this is the last console output: --> Creating Bankaccount Token {country: "AU", currency: "aud", account_holder_name: "Someone Name", account_holder_type: "individual", account_number: "000123456", …}

Comment: ` I'm not sure why, but the code worked when I created a stackblitz.`

 This shot off a ton of red flags to target your compiler options as the culprit. What version of JS are you targeting in your `tsconfig.app.json`? Also, what `lib`s are you including? Async/await are ES7 features, so targeting ES7 or higher will include them as-is, which isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: Also, can you get an `await` to work otherwise with a dummy Promise of your creation? i.e. `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));`?

Comment: Which browser you had issue with? I bet Safari?;)

Comment: @joh04667 I just checked and it appears to be targetting es5, I changed it to ES2017 as this was the allowable option. But this didn't work, same behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko its Chrome on ubuntu.

Comment: @joh04667 I ended up trying what was suggested below as an answer (to use take(1) : .pipe(take(1)).toPromise(); and it worked. I'm uncertain as to why this is working locally, but on stackblitz it worked without having to use take(1)

Comment: Interesting, i saw same symptoms for nested async await in safari. Fixed it by removing nested function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try doing `.pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`.

See the logic on the internal code for rxjs. `resolve` only gets called on completion (see code below). So, depending on how your observable works you may not get the resolution. The `subscribe`, however, will get called even if the observable is not complete, on each value emission which is why your `subscribe` works. `take(1)` will cause a completion, so that should call your promise.

Here is the rxjs code for that function.

```
Observable.prototype.toPromise = function (PromiseCtor) {
    var _this = this;
    if (!PromiseCtor) {
        if (_root.Rx && _root.Rx.config && _root.Rx.config.Promise) {
            PromiseCtor = _root.Rx.config.Promise;
        }
        else if (_root.Promise) {
            PromiseCtor = _root.Promise;
        }
    }
    if (!PromiseCtor) {
        throw new Error('no Promise impl found');
    }
    return new PromiseCtor(function (resolve, reject) {
        var value;
        _this.subscribe(function (x) { return value = x; }, function (err) { return reject(err); }, function () { return resolve(value); });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi I tried this (I imported take from rxjs/operators) and tried createToken("bank_account", account).take(1).toPromise(); but I received "[ts] Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<TokenResult>'."

Comment: I altered this to createToken("bank_account", account).pipe(take(1)).toPromise(); and it worked. Thank you!!!! Is there a reason why it would have worked on stackblitz and not locally ?

Comment: Not sure, might be a versioning issue. As time allows I will try it out. If it helped. I'd appreciate you accept the answer (will modify to include pipe).

Comment: Interestingly I have used the toPromise(); on other observable within the same project without any issues.

Comment: This helped me with a different library (AngularFire) oh man I was so stumped! When I .then() off it, it worked, but async/await just exits without the pipe>take(1)

Comment: pipe(take(1)) is what I needed. This has saved me a large amount of time.

Comment: "Avoid comments like '+1' and 'Thanks'", okay, but I just have to this one time. Thank you so much for pointing out this very not obvious thing! One would think that the `toPromise` call did that internally. I spent two days trying to figure out what was going on..

Comment: This answer saved my days. Thank you!