# Observable works whereas .toPromise() doesn't

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

I am currently trying to call my Firebase Firestore - which works as expected when using the following code:

```
this.store.collection('posts').valueChanges().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Which is good and all but I'd much rather use async/await to get the data. I tried the following:

```
const test = await this.store.collection('posts').valueChanges().toPromise();
```

But `test` is never populated when I place a debugger or console log of `test`. Am I missing something stupid or can you not transform an `Observable` to a promise and await it as above?

Comment: Did you tag your function with `async`?

Comment: @Mic - I did yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593442/async-await-topromise-hangs?rq=1 explains why and gives solution - I'll tag as duplicate :)

Comment: @Mic - thanks I really appreciate it! Makes sense to me now :)